# Wifi connection to scanner not working

Tags: wireless, scanner

I have a Samsung NC10 running Ubuntu 12.04 with wifi connection to a Netgear DG834PN router with wifi connection to an Epson SX515W multi function printer. I also have a desktop machine running 12.04 with wired connection to the router.
The NC10 prints with no problem as does the desktop.  The desktop also operates the scanner with no problem.  If I connect the NC10 with USB to the scanner that also works, but it will not scan while connected to the network wirelessly. 
I have only just updated from 10.04, and it was working perfectly before the update.
Please help.